# What is the proper term for the following class of intervals?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

When we have continuous intervals that may or may not include their endpoints, what should those be called?

Examples:

$(0,1)$

$[0,5)$

$(0,6]$

$[-7,100]$

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is "connected" subsets. In $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology), a subset is connected if and  only if it is an interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Interval" is a sufficiently precise term here. If it has a hole, it is by definition not an interval.

Comment: My question was perhaps poorly worded, what is the generalization of interval for larger dimensions?

Comment: @Makogan you could define intervals in any partially ordered set. As you ask about "larger dimensions" and no "holes", perhaps you might be thinking of simply connected sets? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space

Comment: @Makogan you should reword your question because as it is it does not ask for higher dimensions. Also the term "end point" is not well defined in higher dimensions.